# Is there a protobuf 3 compatible Spring HTTP message converter?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, converters, protocol-buffers

There's a `org.springframework.http.converter.protobuf.ProtobufHttpMessageConverter` that can be used to convert protobuf generated java message classes, but it's tested only with protobuf version 2.5

Is there a version compatible with the version 3 of protobuf?

Comment: No... See https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-13589

Comment: Looks like one needs to use Spring 5.0 M1 or wait for Spring 5 end of this year.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a not fully tested solution still in a git branch:

https://github.com/bclozel/spring-framework/blob/SPR-13589/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/http/converter/protobuf/ProtobufHttpMessageConverter.java